# Flutter - What is the best way to parse Json?

Tags: json, serialization, flutter, deserialization

Actually, I am using the traditional way to work with Json:

```
factory MyObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
```

I have a lot of objects dealing with Json and over time, I encounter problems like:

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'MyObject'#0
```

I am looking for the best way (external plugin or something else) to manipulate these Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [json_serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable) package.

And docs has an excellent [resource](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) about JSON serialization.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at this.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would set up the MyObject class to parse Json

```
class MyObject {
    String value;


    MyObject({this.value});

    static MyObject fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> map){
      var value = map['value'];

      return MyObject(value:value);
    }
}
```